# Bootstrap 100% height with navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is basically what I want to achieve:

[image: Example]

I want the total page to be 100% height, but when I put the sidebar and body at 100%, the page adds the 40px from the navbar, so I get a scrollbar even when there shouldn't be one.

I got it fixed by using tables, but I'm sure there must be an easier way

```
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar"></div>
        <div class="sidebar"></div>
        <div class="body"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

and css what I've got so far:

```
body, html, .container-fluid, .sidebar, .body {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
.navbar {
    height: 40px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You'll have to subtract the height of the navbar from the 100%. There are several solutions, many of which will include JavaScript but you won't need that.

**1: box-sizing**

Give the navbar an absolute position. Then you have the issue of the content of the other elements disappearing below it.
Then comes the next trick: add a top-padding the size of the navbar.
And the last trick: add `box-sizing: border-box;` to the `.sidebar` and `.body`. For better browser support you also need -moz- and -webkit- prefixes like so: `-moz-box-sizing:`

Example: [Fiddle to box-sizing](http://jsfiddle.net/W2zkL/)

**2: Actually subtract.**

use `.body, .sidebar{ height: calc(100% - 40px);`
Browser support is <s>very minimal for this from what I know</s> less than for box-sizing, so I would recommend the first solution.
[Calc explained on css-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/a-couple-of-use-cases-for-calc/)

**3: Flexbox(added anno 2015)**

You should now probably go with using calc when you know the height but an awesome replacement for using tables is flexbox. This is really my saviour for complex designs in responsive websites. By using one of the best features - `flex-shrink: 0` - on the header you can force other elements into adjusting themselves to fill the rest of the container.

An old answer is probably not the best place to write down an extensive guide on flexbox so, again, a great link to [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: In terms of `calc()` support, it's actually [surprisingly good](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc). I was also under the impression that support was almost non-existent

Comment: Thank you, edited my answer with that knowledge. Unfortunately IE8 still has a decent market share. I should have known, I did check that caniuse page before. My mind probably interpreted it as -can not use for own project, so no support-

Comment: I have several sections with 100% height. For the first section, I use `height: calc(100% - 56px)` to account for the `navbar` at the top. But I would like to eliminate the magic number 56 from the code and use something else that automatically adjusts the height according to the height of the `navbar`. What do you suggest me to use? I'm using the bootstrap 4 navbar

Answer (score 1):

Probably because it is adding the default margin from the navbar. Try this:

```
.navbar {
    height: 40px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Also, try changing the min to max height:

```
max-height: 100% !important;
```

Comment: But then the page is still giving me a 40px scrollbar, because the sidebar and body div are height 100%, and the navbar is height 40px, which is 100% + 40px

Comment: `.navbar {
    line-height: 50px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}` is working for me

Answer (score -1):

I change a litle your code by adding a container around your side bar and body class:

Here is the [RESULT](http://jsfiddle.net/uqbXM/19/)

**Css:**

```
body, html, .container-fluid, .sidebar, .body {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}

#container{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}


.sidebar{
    background-color: green;
    width:10%;
    float:left;
    height:100%;

}

.body{
    background-color: orange;
    float:left;
    width:90%;
    height:100%;

}

.navbar {
    height: 40px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: yellow;
    width:100%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar">
        navbar
    </div>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="sidebar">
            sidebar
        </div>
        <div class="body">
            body
        </div>
      </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Thanks but then I still get a 40px scrollbar