# Side navbar not filling full height

Tags: css, navbar

I had a lot of problems with the design and layout of my site.  I've fixed most of them now, but one chief one remains: my side nav not taking up the full height of the text-container (or going beyond the size).  I had hoped that by adding a middle container and setting the side nav to have a height: 100% would do the trick, but it's not.

[code]

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Home  </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./main.css">
<link rel="icon" href="./ski_icon.png">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="jquery-3.0.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body> 
<div id='content'><div id='logo'><img src='./logo.png'></img></div><div id='container'><nav id='hor'><ul><li><a href='./index.php'> Home </a> </li><li><a href='./mountains.php'> The Mountains </a></li><li><a href='./resorts.php'> The Resorts </a></li><li><a href='./snowreports.php'> Snow Reports </a></li><li class='dropdown' id='Events'><a href='javascript:void(0)' class='dropbtn' id='events2' onclick='showEAndADropdownHor()'> Events &amp Activities <i class='fa fa-angle-down'></i></a><div class='dropdown-content' id='eAndADropdown'><ul><li><a href='./eventsandactivities.php'> Main </a></li><br/><li> <a href='./foggyGoggle.php'> Foggy Goggle </a></li><br/><li><a href='./lessons.php'>  Ski Lessons </a></li></ul></div>


</li><li><a href='./plantrip.php'> Plan A Trip </a></li><li><a href='./contactus.php'> Contact Us </a></li><li><a href='./findus.php'> Find Us </a></li><li class='dropdown' id='Restaurants'> <a href='javascript:void(0)' class='dropbtn' onclick='showRestaurantDropdownHor()'> Restaurants <i class='fa fa-angle-down'></i></a><div class='dropdown-content' id='restaurantDropdown' style='z-index: 1;'><ul style><li><a href='./grandviewbistro.php'>Grand View Bistro</a></li><br/><li><a href='./angelescrestcafe.php'>Angeles Crest Caf&eacute</a></li><br/> <li><a href='./goldrushgrill.php'>Goldrush Grill</a></li><br/><li><a href='./bullwheelbarandgrill.php'>  Bullwheel Bar &amp  Grill </a></li><br/><li><a href='./bigpinesbarbecue.php'> Big Pines Barbecue </a></li><br/><li><a href='./northpolegrill.php'> North Pole Grill </a></li></ul></div>

</li></ul></nav><div id='middleContainer'><div id='middle'><nav id='vert'><ul><li><a href='./index.php'> Home </a></li><li><a href='./mountains.php'> The Mountains </a></li><tr><td><li><a href='./resorts.php'> The Resorts </a></li></td></tr><li><a href='./snowreports.php'> Snow Reports </a></li><li class='dropdown'  id='ead2'><a href='javascript:void(0)' class='dropbtn' onclick='showEAndADropdownVert()'> Events &amp Activities <i class='fa fa-angle-right'></i> </a><div class='dropdown-content' id='eAndADropdown2'><ul id='sb'><li><a href='./eventsandactivities.php'> Main </a></li><li> <a href='./foggyGoggle.php'> Foggy Goggle </a></li><li><a href='./lessons.php'>  Ski Lessons </a></li></ul></div></li>
<script>

function changePage()
{





window.location.href= "./findus.php";

}

</script>

<li><a href='./plantrip.php'> Plan A Trip </a></li><li><a href='./contactus.php'> Contact Us </a></li><li onclick='changePage()'><a href='./findus.php'> Find Us</a></li><li class='dropdown'> <a href='javascript:void(0)' class='dropbtn' onclick='showRestaurantDropdownVert()'> Restaurants <i class='fa fa-angle-right'></i></a><div class='dropdown-content' id='restaurantDropdown2'><ul><li><a href='./grandviewbistro.php'>Grand View Bistro</a></li><li><a href='./angelescrestcafe.php'>Angeles Crest Caf&eacute</a></li> <li><a href='./goldrushgrill.php'>Goldrush Grill</a></li><li><a href='./bullwheelbarandgrill.php'>  Bullwheel Bar &amp  Grill </a></li><li><a href='./bigpinesbarbecue.php'> Big Pines Barbecue </a></li><li><a href='./northpolegrill.php'> North Pole Grill </a></li></ul></div></li></ul></nav>

<style>

img
{
width: 250;
height: 250;
border: 1px solid black;

}

</style>

</div>



 <div id="text-container">

<h1> Home</h1>

<p> Looking for an exciting day of fun?   Then you've come to the right place!   Diamond Peaks Resort is rated #1 by the All-American Skiing Association.   
With three different resorts, there is enough variety to please everyone.   </p>

<img src="./image2.jpg"></img><img src="./image5.jpg"></img><img src="./image3.jpg"></img><br/>
<img src="./image6.jpg"></img><img src="./image7.jpg"></img><img src="./image12.jpg"></img><br/>


  </div>
</div>
</div>


<div id='footercontainer' style='height: 90px;'><footer style='height: 90px;'>
<style>

a.twitter-share-button 
{
color:  white;

}

footer table.right td
{
background-color: rgb(223,223,223);

}

footer table.left td
{
font-family: "Impact", Times, serif;
font-size: 14px;
color: white;


}


footer  table.left td a
{
color: white;
font-family: "Impact", Times, serif;
font-size: 14px;

}

</style>
<div style='float: left;'>1234 Easy Street San Gabriel, CA <br/>Copyright  &copy;  2016   Dimaond Peaks Resort, &nbsp; All Rights Reserved. <br/><a href='http://www.allwebpromotion.com/' target='_blank'>Website Design</a> by: All Web Promotion</div><div style='float:right; color: black;'><a href='https://twitter.com/share' class='twitter-share-button' data-text='Come to Diamond Peaks Resort and enjoy the fun!' data-size='large'>Tweet</a> <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>







</div>
<br/>
</div>
</footer></div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

[/code]

[code]

```
#logo
{

border: 1px dashed purple;
width: 1050;
height: 75;

}

#logo > img
{
width: 1050;
height: 75;

}

footer a
{

color: white;


}

.floatleft
{
float: left;

}


.floatright
{
float: right;

}

#content
{

// border-left: 3px solid #283379;
  border-right: 3px solid #283379;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0 auto;


max-width: 960px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  height: auto;





}



nav#hor ul li ul
{
overflow-y: auto;



}

nav
{


      border: 10px solid transparent;
padding: 15px;
  border-image-source: url(./blue-diamond.gif);  
  border-image-repeat:repeat;
   border-image-slice: 30;

background-color: 2211ff;
font-family: "Impact", Times, serif;
font-size: 110%;

}

nav#vert
{

 width: auto;

  height: 100%;  

  margin: 0px;
 //display:table-cell;
 // float: left;
font-size: 100%;

}

nav#hor ul li ul li
{

width: 100%;

}

.dropdown ul li
{
width: 100%;

}


.dropdown-content ul li
{
width: 100%;


}






body { 
  color: #000000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: #422520;
  background-image: url(./snow_mountain.jpg);
   background-repeat:no-repeat;

   background-size:cover;
  text-align: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
}

#footerContainer
{

 //border-left: 3px solid #283379;
  border-right: 3px solid #283379;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 980px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
height: 150px;


}

footer
{

    border: 10px solid transparent;
padding: 15px;


  text-align: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1000px;

  background-repeat: repeat-y;

  border-image-source: url(./blue-diamond.gif);  
  border-image-repeat:repeat;
   border-image-slice: 30;

background-color: 2211ff;
font-family: "Impact", Times, serif;
font-size: 14px;
color: white;


}

footer table.left td
{
font-family: "Impact", Times, serif;
font-size: 14px;
color: white;


}


footer  table.left td a
{
color: white;
font-family: "Impact", Times, serif;
font-size: 14px;

}

#container
{
 // border-left: 3px solid #283379;
  border-right: 3px solid #283379;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1050px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  height: auto;
 // max-width: 960px;




}


nav > a
{

color: #ccccff;

}

nav#hor > div
{

border: 1px solid white;
float: left;
padding: 10px;
background-color: #000044;
}

nav#hor
{
max-width: 1000px;
//width: auto;
height: 50px;
margin: 0;
font-size: 100%;
//width: 960px;

}


nav#hor a
{

//color: rgb(0 0,238);
color: white;
}


nav#hor > div >  a
{

color:  #ccccff;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 100%;
}



nav#hor>div:hover
{

background-color: #018802;

}

h1
{
font-family: "MV Boli", Times, Serif;

font-style: bold;
text-align: center;
font-size: 36px;

}

h2
{

font-family: "MV Boli", Times, Serif;
font-style: bold;
text-align: center;
font-size: 26px;
}

h3
{

font-family: "MV Boli", Times, Serif;
font-style: bold;
text-align: center;
font-size: 20px;
}




#text-container
{



height: 100%;
width: auto;

border: 2px solid cyan;




  */ zoom: 1;
  */ margin: 0;
  display: table-cell;


 padding-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;




}


nav#hor li
{

width: auto;


}

#text-container:after
{
clear: both;
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  visibility:hidden;

}

#text-container  p
{
font-family: "Myriad Web Pro", Times, Serif;
font-size: 18px;
}

.left img
{

float: left; 
padding: 0 20px 20px 0;

}






.left > p
{
font-family: "Myriad Web Pro", Times, Serif;
font-size: 18px;
}


.right img
{
float: right;
    margin: 0px 0px 15px 20px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;

}



.right  p
{
font-family: "Myriad Web Pro", Times, Serif;
font-size: 18px;
}


nav#hor ul
{
list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
 background-color: #000044;
   z-index: 1;

    width: auto;
    overflow: hidden;






}

nav#hor ul li:hover
{
  background-color: #018802;

}







nav#vert ul
{
list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
   // overflow: auto;
    background-color: #000044;
      height: auto;



}

nav#vert  li a
{
display: block;

}
nav#hor ul li
{
float: left;
border: 1px solid white;
z-index: 1;
width: auto;


}

nav#vert ul li
{
//float: left;
border: 1px solid white;.
z-index: 1;
position: relative;


}

nav#vert a
{
color: white;

}

#middle
{
height: 100%;
float: left;

width: auto;

 display: table-cell;

}




nav#vert ul li ul
{
//left: 100%;

//left: 25;
//right:: 150;
//left: 215px;
//right: 20%;

 //top: 100%;
//  left: 0;
  //right: 100%;
  //right: -50px;
  //bottom: 100%;
  //top: 0;
  //float: right;
   //right: -100px;

top: -36px;
left: 90%;



position: absolute;
//height: 164px;
height: auto;


}




nav#vert  li a, .dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
  //  color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 8px 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
}


 nav#hor  li a, .dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
  //  color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 8px 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav#vert li:hover
{
 background-color: #018802;

}

nav#hor   li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
 background-color: #018802;

}

nav#vert   li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #018802;
}


 li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}



.dropdown-content ul
{

z-index: 1000;


}
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
      color: rgb(0, 0, 238);
     z-index: 1000;



}

.dropdown-content-side
{


}

#eAndADropdown
{

}

#eAndADropdown2
{

}


#eAndADropdown ul li
{
background-color: #000044;
border: 1px solid white;

}

#restaurantDropdown ul li
{
background-color: #000044;
border: 1px solid white;

}

#restaurantDropdown  ul
{
border: 1px solid white;

}

#eAndADropdown ul
{
border: 1px solid white;

}


#eAndADropdown:hover
{
  background-color: #018802;

}

#restaurantDropdown:hover
{
  background-color: #018802;

}

#eAndADropdown a
{
    color: rgb(0, 0, 238);

}

#restaurantDropdown a
{
    color: rgb(0, 0, 238);

}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: rgb(0, 0, 238);
     border: 1 px solid white;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}



.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.show {display:block;}

li  a
{

color: rgb(0, 0, 238);

}
```

[/code]

BTW, I'm wondering if my display: table-cell; for the nav#vert (or was it #middle) and the #text-container  to try and fix a problem that was leaving no padding for the #text-container (though it broke a few other things, but I think I fixed that by making some adjustments, at least,  I think I fixed it.  Anyway, I'm wondering if my display: table-cell is the reason the navbar is messed up or is it something else?)

Comment: Please reduce your code to the minimum amount required to show the problem. Often that will magically reveal the answer to you and save you the hassle of coming here. If not, it helps us find the problem much easier because nothing else is in the way. Also, please format your code (with indentations, no superfluous space) so we can read it.

Comment: I have removed some of the unneeded stuff.

Comment: Hmmm, would calc work?

Comment: Here is more of what I'm after:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17401972/bootstrap-100-height-with-navbar

Comment: I don't get it.  I'm trying everything I'm finding and nothing is working.

Answer (score 1):

Whats your goal? to achieve the blue color at the side bar? if so..
add to *middleContainer* background: #21f;
and to *text-container*  background: #fff;

> Update:
>   You haven't declared *middleContainer* element. Adding the element to your css might fix your issue.

```
#middleContainer {
     height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: No, my left navbar is either not going down to the footer or it's going into the footer.    I thought adding middle container and height 100% would fix it but guess not.

Comment: It might be because it's floated that the 100% thing isn't working.

Comment: It was in my CSS.   I added it.  Still hasn't helped.

Comment: I did it locally works just fine. try to clear your cache

Comment: I was using the incognito mode.  There isn't a cache there.

Comment: If it worked, you must have changed other things too, because all it did on its own was break more things.

Comment: At any rate, it is now working enough, and I've spent at least a day or more just on this issue.

Comment: Good job then (:

Answer (score 0):

Removing the #middle element has resolved the issue.