# Page layout using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, layout, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is it possible to get this page layout using Bootstrap 3?

[image]

Header is fluid. 
Navigation is 250px wide and 100% in height. Content takes up the rest.

When it comes to content, Bootstrap is brilliant. But I struggle to get the desired result when it comes to dividing the page the way I want.

Could go for Flexbox as mentioned here [Bootstrap 100% height with navbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17401972/bootstrap-100-height-with-navbar), but I need support for IE10.

Can this be done entirely in Bootstrap with minor adjustments or do I have to go with a separate file for the layout?

Comment: The fastest way to get to this result is using a CSS separate file for the layout. It will be easier to update and cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12" style="background-color:grey; text-align:center;">Header</div>
    </div>
  <div class="row" >
    <div style="background-color:lightcyan; text-align:center;" class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4">Navigation</div>
    <div style="background-color:lightgrey; text-align:center;" class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-lg-8">Content</div>
  </div>

    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use bootstrap but with custom css file. [example here](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/eNe4v)

Answer (score 1):

This could be a *CSS* file linked to your bootstrap design. It will be quite easier to update, and you will have a clear separation between global layout design and content design.

```css
html, body {
  margin : 0px;
  width : 100%;
  height : 100vh;
}

body .header {
  width : 100%
  height : 10vh;
  background-color : #aaa;
}

body .flex-line {
  display : flex;
}

body .nav {
  width : 250px;
  height : 100%;
  background-color : #ccc;
}

body .content {
  width : 100%;
  height : 100%;
  background-color : #eee;
}

p {
  text-align : center;
  font-family : Arial;
}
```

```html
<html>
  
  <body>
  
   <div class="header">
    <p>Header</p>
   </div>
   
   
   <div class="flex-line">
     <div class="nav">
      <p>Navigation</p>
     </div>

     <div class="content">
      <p>Content</p>
     </div>
   </div>
   
  </body>
  
</html>
```

I hope it will be helpfull.